# 403 Forbidden Error while building Google Endpoints backend in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, httpexception

It is my first time trying to use GAE endpoints connecting in an Android Studio project. So, I've simply followed the instructions provided by Google (https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/app_engine/). But I am getting a 403 error every time I attempt to build or run backend module. Here is the message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: 403 Forbidden
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/generate/rest</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Usually I could suppress this kind of issues by enabling a proxy in Settings. But for this error, after googling for 3 days and trying all solutions flashed in my mind, nothing changed. Anyone has encountered the same error? or know a solution/suggestion?

**Edit**
I am running the template Endpoint project with sample MyBean and MyEndpoint classes without any changes. Here is related build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the relevant Java code please.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Java code is unchanged from sample Hello Endpoints! project. I've added gradle build settings in edit section

Answer (score 1):

Google blocks access of people in some countries including Iran to http://developer.google.com and http://apis.google.com, so you are having problems.

You should avoid **Google App Engine** anyway, because of *privacy*, *portability* and several other concerns.

> **Portability concerns**
>
> Developers worry that the applications will not be portable from App
>   Engine and fear being locked into the technology. In response, there
>   are a number of projects to create open-source back-ends for the
>   various proprietary/closed APIs of app engine, especially the
>   datastore. AppScale, CapeDwarf and TyphoonAE are a few of the open
>   source efforts.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine#Portability_concerns

You can use these alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for response @Ho1. Actually, portability or other GAE main drawbacks our not my concerns. I am working for an employer outside the  Iran where the whole project will be deployed. I had this issue from downloading the framework to using developers features but a proxy server made it possible for me to develop and test apps inside Google environment. for this particular issue, is it possible to use a proxy setting for Java httprequests at test?

Comment: Yes. But VPN would be a better choice.